# Compiler Directive to check if Skia is enabled on my Delphi FIreMonkey App?

Tags: delphi, skia, compiler-directives, skia4delphi, delphi-12-athens

Is there a compiler directive or some kind of directive that I can use to check in the code if Skia is enabled or not for the platform that I am compiling to?

I have a form that is used in multiple projects, but I don't have Skia enabled for all the projects. So I'd like compiler directives to basically see if Skia is on or not and then include the Skia units based on that directive.

I am using the Delphi Programming language and Delphi 12 IDE

Answer (score 0):

There is no *compiler* directive, no. You will have to make up your own conditional if you want that. Enabling Skia on the project level simply links in the necessary library files for deployment, nothing more.

If you want FMX's default `Canvas` to *use* Skia, you have to [manually set `GlobalUseSkia=True`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Skia4Delphi#App_render) in your own code, and you can wrap that with per-platform compiler directives as needed.

But, if you just want to use Skia by itself, that is not needed.

Comment: How do I make my own conditional for this? How do I wrap that like you're mentioning?

Comment: Create a [custom define in the Project Options](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler), or use [{$DEFINE}](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DEFINE_directive_(Delphi)) in your code.